# How to uninstall Python 2.7.16 on a macOS Catalina Version 10.15.7 or how to switch to Python 3.9.2?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, uninstallation

Already have python3 but python2 is giving me conflict.

How to transition to using python3 from within terminal and how to prevent picking up python2 version?

Comment: You might have better luck on the [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) website (<https://apple.stackexchange.com/>).

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7 comes with macOS as part of the OS, you can't remove it without causing major issues...

I recommend using [venv](http://%20%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) (virtual environment) in order to install/run other python versions on macOS

Comment: I have the python3 but python2 is giving me conflict

Comment: @Diana if you'll use venv it'll create a "clean" environment on which you can install any python version (and any package) without conflicts. That's exactly what venv is for.